# How to prove that $\int_0^1 \exp\left(\frac{4x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{8x^2+1}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{1-8x^2+16x^4}{1+7x^2-8x^4}}dx=e-1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

show that

> $$\int\limits_0^1 {\exp \left( {\frac{{4x\sqrt {1 - {x^2}} }}{{\sqrt {8{x^2} + 1} }}} \right)} \sqrt {\frac{{1 - 8{x^2} + 16{x^4}}}{{1 + 7{x^2} - 8{x^4}}}} dx = e - 1$$

I think this is nice integral,This problem is my china frend give me do it at yesterday, But I can't prove it. Thank you

my try:let 
$$u=\dfrac{4x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{8x^2+1}}$$

then $$du=-\dfrac{4(8x^4+2x^2-1)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(8x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Comment: The right hand side is $\int_0^1 e^udu$. Have you tried substituting the exponent? ie. $u = \frac{4x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{8x^2+1}}$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan,I have try it,But not any usefull..

Comment: Plotting the integrand is enough to convince me that you'll want to either split the integral into parts at $1/2$, and maybe use some sort of symmetry around that point.

Comment: some people say this integral is not easy.and I think must use  Integration of other methods

Comment: If this function had an elementary anti-derivative, you'd have your answer by now.  As it stands, it means that there's some sort of nice cancellation: perhaps the only non-elementary "part" of your integral has symmetry about $x=1/2$.

Comment: Is it easier for someone to prove that integral of $$\exp\left(\frac{4x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{8x^2+1}}\right)\frac{3x}{\left(1+2 x^2 \right)^2}$$ from $0$ to $0.5$ equals to same integral from $0.5$ to $1$? If someone is able to prove this, then this problem will be solved.

Comment: @Ruslan How did you obtain that $3x$ in the numerator and that $(1+2x^2)^2$ in the denominator?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas I subtracted RHS after converting it to integral and making its limits $0$ and $1$, and used integration by parts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let us note that  under the change of variables $y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+8x^2}}$ we have  $x=\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{1+8y^2}}$ and the interval $(0,\frac12)$ is mapped to $(\frac12,1)$ and vice versa. Also,
$$\frac{1-4x^2}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+8x^2)}}dx=\frac{3(4y^2-1)dy}{(1+8y^2)\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1+8y^2)}}$$

Now our integral can be written as
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1e^{4xy}\frac{|1-4x^2|}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+8x^2)}}dx=\\
=&\int_0^{\frac12}e^{4xy}\frac{1-4x^2}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+8x^2)}}dx+\int_{\frac12}^1e^{4xy}\frac{4x^2-1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+8x^2)}}dx=\\
=&\int_0^{\frac12}e^{4xy}\frac{1-4x^2}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+8x^2)}}dx+\int_0^{\frac12}e^{4xy}\frac{3(1-4y^2)}{(1+8y^2)\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1+8y^2)}}dy=\\
=&\int_0^{\frac12}e^{4xy}\frac{1-4x^2}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+8x^2)}}dx+\int_0^{\frac12}e^{4xy}\frac{3(1-4x^2)}{(1+8x^2)\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+8x^2)}}dx=\\
=&\int_0^{\frac12}e^{4xy}\frac{4(1-4x^2)(1+2x^2)}{(1+8x^2)\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1+8x^2)}}dx=\\
=&\int_0^{\frac12}e^{4xy}(4xy)'_xdx=\\
=&\left[\exp 4x\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+8x^2}}\,\right]_{0}^{\frac12}=\\
=&e-1.
\end{align}

Comment: I take off my hat to you!!

Comment: It's nice! Thank you +1